# NumPy dot prodoct of a 2d array and a 3D array element wise

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
A = np.array([[1,1],
              [2,2],
              [3,3]])

B = np.array([[[1],[2]],[[3],[4]]])
```

I think of `B` as an array of 2 matrix, what I want to achieve is to do dot product between `A` and each element of `B`, to get:

```
[[[3],
  [6],
  [9]], 
 [[7],
  [14],
  [21]]]
```

but if I do `np.dot(A,B)`, I get

```
[[3,7],
 [6,14],
 [9,21]]
```

how to get what I want here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html), like so -

```
A.dot(B).T[0,...,None]
```

Or with [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) -

```
np.tensordot(B[...,0], A, axes=((1),(1)))[...,None]
```

Or [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('ijk,lj->ilk',B,A)
```

`np.matmul` seems to be working as well without any additional work -

```
np.matmul(A,B)
```

Comment: Or in python > 3.5, `A @ B`